# General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to assign the user_id with the current user but it give me this error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a 
default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (2017-04-27 10:29:59, 2017-04-27 10:29:59))
```

here is my method

```
//PostController
Post::create(request([
        'body' => request('body'),
        'title' => request('title'),
        'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ]));
```

with these fillables

```
//Post Model
protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'user_id']
```

However this method do the job

```
//PostController
auth()->user()->publish(new Post(request(['title' ,'body']))); 

//Post Model
public function publish(Post $post)
{
    $this->posts()->save($post);
}
```

any idea why this fail?
[image]

Comment: It's clear enough: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value. In your post table set nullable for user_id. Or in migration $table->int('user_id')->nullable(); or as Saman says dump the value of auth()->id. And by the way i think it's auth()->id without brackets

Comment: it seems `user_id` can not retrieval . add some number instead `auth()->id()` and try

Comment: Are you getting some value of user_id, have you dd/echo user_id?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan yes I do. When I dd(auth()->id()) it works!

Comment: @Mohammed Sabbah: ok, means your problem has been resolved?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan no still the same error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a 
default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (2017-04-27 10:29:59, 2017-04-27 10:29:59))`

Comment: on your database table 'user_id' column is of which type? I t must be integer.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan it is an integer

Comment: @Muhammed Sabbah: ok , check this column default value? Insert some row into this table and see what's value is going to this column by default.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan it did not have default value. Do it need to have default value?

Comment: @Muhammed Sabbah: ok.put 0 as a default value into this column and run your code and see what happens.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan it now give me this `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'body' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2017-04-27 11:22:48, 2017-04-27 11:22:48))` why? also it give the same for title, why?!

Comment: Take screenshot of your table structure and show it along with your question

Comment: Check Comrade answer below

Comment: @Mohammed Sabbah:Have you check Comrade answer below..and try it

Answer (score 33, accepted):

So, after After reviewing the code again, I found the error.
I am wondering how no one notice that!
In the above code I wrote

```
Post::create(request([  // <= the error is Here!!!
    'body' => request('body'),
    'title' => request('title'),
    'user_id' => auth()->id()
]));
```

actually, there is no need for the request function warping the body of the create function.

```
// this is right
Post::create([
    'body' => request('body'),
    'title' => request('title'),
    'user_id' => auth()->id()
]);
```

Comment: auth()->id() or auth()->id?

Comment: Also ensure that you have the fields as mass assignable

Answer (score 50):

you need to change database strict mode. for disable follow below step

1. Open `config/database.php`
2. find `'strict'` change the value true to false and try again

Comment: I tried it, it did not give me the error, but it store an empty column on the database!

Comment: sorry I ment row.

Answer (score 33):

I've had a similar issue with User registration today and I was getting a

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into users
```

I fixed it by adding `password` to my protected $fillable array and it worked

```
protected $fillable = [
  'name',
  'email',
  'password',
];
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Even if it seems to be present in the fillable array, recheck it as there might be a typo lurking there :( learnt the hard way.

Comment: I always forget to add to fillable, easy step to miss. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 14):

Here's how I did it:

This is my PostsController

```
Post::create([

    'title' => request('title'),
    'body' => request('body'),
    'user_id' => auth()->id() 
]);
```

And this is my Post Model.

```
protected $fillable = ['title', 'body','user_id'];
```

And try refreshing the migration if its just on test instance

```
$ php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Note: migrate: refresh will delete all the previous posts, users

Comment: Adding the `user_id` to fillable will solve the problem if you don't have a syntax error in the controller, but why are you refreshing the migration?

Answer (score 3):

### Try using `Auth::id()`, like

```
Post::create([ 'body' => request('body'), 'title' => request('title'), 'user_id' => Auth::id()]);
```

also remember to include Auth facade at top of your controller which is `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`

Comment: I do not use Auth facade, however when I `dd(auth()->id())` it works!

Answer (score 3):

Try

`'user_id' => auth()->id`
or

`'user_id' => Auth::user()->id`

instead of

```
'user_id' => auth()->id()
```

Comment: it fail `Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$id`

Comment: what is the value of Auth::user()->id ?

Comment: the value is the login user id

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions for this issue.

First, is to create fields with default values set in datatable. It could be empty string, which is fine for MySQL server running in strict mode.

Second, if you started to get this error just recently, after MySQL/MariaDB upgrade, like I did, and in case you already have large project with a lot to fix, all you need to do is to edit MySQL/MariaDB configuration file (for example `/etc/my.cnf`) and disable strict mode for tables:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

This error started to happen quite recently, due to new strict mode enabled by default. Removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from `sql_mode` configuration key, makes it work as before.

Answer (score 2):

User `Auth::user()->id` instead.

Here is the correct way :

```
//PostController
Post::create(request([
    'body' => request('body'),
    'title' => request('title'),
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
]));
```

If your user is authenticated, Then `Auth::user()->id` will do the trick.

Comment: And use Auth in controller

Comment: You can use `Auth::user()->id` in views too.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan I do not use Auth facade from the begining. I am following the [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/19) tutorial, and the instructor also did not use it.

Comment: The instructor is jeffery way, He is great.

Comment: Sure, he is one of the best. I do what he did, but I do not know why this fail! I am wondering why the second method did the job well?

Comment: @MohammedSabbah Please accept one of the answer, If that solves the problem, Good day.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was because I had not declared the field in my $fillable array in the model. Well, it seems to be something basic, but for us who started with laravel it could work.

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r(Auth);`

then see in which format you have user_id / id variable and use it

Comment: Dumping the whole auth will consume all the memory, if you want to dump the `user_id` do `print_r(auth()->id())`

Answer (score 0):

It's seems flaw's in your database structure. Keep default value None to your title and body column.

Try this:

```
$user_login_id = auth()->id();
Post::create(request([
        'body' => request('body'),
        'title' => request('title'),
        'user_id' => $user_login_id
    ]));
```

Comment: I tried it, it give me this error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'body' doesn't have a default value`. This is why I tried to put a default value for it.

Comment: Have you manually create this table ? or run migration files?

Comment: I ran migration files.

Comment: it is utf8mb4_unicode_ci, when I change to your suggestion it give me syntax error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'`

Comment: You also need to change it into your config/database.php file

Comment: it did not work. sorry but I think the problem is not in my database since the second choice work `auth()->user()->publish(new Post(request(['title' ,'body'])));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Post::create([
      'title' => request('title'),
      'body' => request('body'),
      'user_id' => auth()->id()
    ]);
```

you dont need the request() as you doing that already pulling the value of body and title

Answer (score 0):

The above error can be as a result of wrongly named input variables from the view form, which resorts to seeking a default value since no variable is supplied hence-- SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a 
default value (SQL: insert into `posts` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values (2017-04-27 10:29:59, 2017-04-27 10:29:59))

Comment: This makes sense and is worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->date('user_id')->nullable();
```

In your file `create_file`, the null option must be enabled.

Comment: updating my column to nullable was the only thing that worked in my case. You can do this by creating a new migration and updating the problematic column using a code very similar to the one above. Just add ->change() to the end. E.g `$table->date('user_id')->nullable()->change();`

Answer (score -1):

Use database column nullble() in Laravel. You can choose the default value or nullable value in database.